# Redefine a SymPy symbol globally (global subs)

Tags: python, sympy

I can't seem to find what I'm looking for in the SymPy docs: basically what I'd like to do is to redefine a symbol so it changes in every expression.

Something like this:

```
from sympy import *

x, y = symbols("x y")

expr1 = 2*x + y
expr2 = x**2 + 2*y

x.redefine("foo")
print(expr1, expr2)

x.redefine(2)
print(expr1, expr2)
```

Output:

```
2*foo + y, foo**2 + 2*y
4 + y, 4 + 2*y
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Sympy is designed in such a way that it cannot be redefined permanently. However, you can use the below command to substitute your symbol in an expression. [Here](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/basic_operations.html) is the documentation for it.

```
expr1.subs({x:"foo"}) #for changing only one symbol.
expr2.subs({x:10, y:20}) #for changing both the symbols.
```

Comment: Using subs is not practical if i have a lot of expressions, or a big matrix

Comment: Yes. But there Sympy has no feature to redefine.

Comment: @lugiank Applying subs to a matrix broadcasts it to all the entries.

Answer (score 0):

SymPy expressions are **immutable**: they never change. Hence, there can be no global switch that implicitly modifies all preexisting expressions.

To handle substitution in multiple expressions, one can use loops, list comprehension, or apply `subs` to a matrix. Examples:

```
expressions = [2*x + y, x**2 + 2*y, x - y/2]
print([expr.subs(x, 3) for expr in expressions])
mat = Matrix(expressions)
print(mat.subs(x, 3))
```

This prints:

```
[y + 6, 2*y + 9, -y/2 + 3]
Matrix([[y + 6], [2*y + 9], [-y/2 + 3]])
```